# Pierre Fatou translation articles

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-dynamics

A friend of mine is studying complex dynamics and require some information of the papers:

1. Sur les equations fonctionnelles 1919 Pierre Fatou
2. Sur les equations fonctionnelles 1920 Pierre Fatou

The problem is that these papers are only found in French language and we have a problem in translation. Does anyone know someone who has translated them in English? If so, could he lend us hand?

Thank you for your time, reading this question

Comment: If anybody wants the original three papers, they seem to be at http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1919__47__161_0/ and http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1920__48__33_0/ and http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1920__48__208_1/ - at a couple of hundred pages, there may not be a translation

Comment: Google Translate does a good job on the first page...

Comment: maybe https://bookstore.ams.org/hmath-38

Comment: You can also ask that question on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because HSM might be bettr.